# How do I get the character count of words in a particular column?

Tags: shell, columns, csv, wc

I have a CSV file like this:

```
abd,123,egypt,78
cde,456,england,45
```

How can I get the character count of only the 3rd column words?

I can't figure out how to get `wc` to do this.

Answer (score 23):

```
awk -F, '{sum+=length($3)}; END {print +sum}' file
```

Comment: Amen; `awk` was designed for processing column based files, line-by-line. The problem is perfectly suited for the tool.

Comment: What is the purpose of + in {print +sum} ?  {print sum} works just as well.

Comment: @spuder, that's to print `0` instead of an empty line when the input file is empty.

Comment: @Ray, on the other hand, the task can be achieved by having 3 basic utilities (each one of them being a fraction of the size of `awk`) cooperating to the case (working concurrently) in typical Unix spirit. You may notice how the cut+tr+wc one is 5 types as fast as this awk one itself 5 times as fast as the `perl` one. (at least on my system, in a UTF8 locale, tried on a 100MB file).

Answer (score 23):

```
cut -d, -f3 | tr -d '\n' | wc -m
```

(remember that `wc -c` counts bytes, not characters:

```
$ echo a,1,españa,2 | cut -d, -f3 | tr -d '\n' | wc -c
7
$ echo a,1,españa,2 | cut -d, -f3 | tr -d '\n' | wc -m
6
```

)

Comment: But he specifies 'I am not able to use `wc` command to get output!'

Comment: @mikeserv, which I interpret as _I wasn't able to get `wc` to give me the character count_ which is why I show how to use `wc` in this context.

Comment: Oh.... That is a *very* valid interpretation which never at all occurred to me...

Answer (score 5):

A `perl` solution:

```
perl -Mopen=:locale -F, -anle '$sum += length($F[2]); END{print $sum}' file
```

or a shorter version:

```
perl -Mopen=:locale -F, -anle '$sum += length($F[2])}{print $sum' file
```

Comment: Note that it returns a byte count, not necessarily a character count.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: length() return the logical characters count, not physical bytes according to perldoc.

Comment: But you need `-Mopen=:locale` for `perl` to use the user/system's definition of what a character is, otherwise it assumes characters are bytes. Try on a `a,1,españa,2` input in a UTF-8 locale (the default on most systems).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Oh, updated my answer. Thanks for good point!

Answer (score 3):

In Perl:

```
perl -F, -Mopen=:locale -lane 'print length $F[2]' your_file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cut -d, -f3 <<\DATA | grep -o . | grep -c .
abd,123,egypt,78
cde,456,england,45
DATA

#OUTPUT
12
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use

```
awk -F, '{printf "%s", $3}' file | wc -m
```

Answer (score 1):

With your sample file like so:

```
$ cat sample.txt 
abd,123,egypt,78
cde,456,england,45

$ awk -F, '{print $3}' sample.txt | while read i; do echo "$i" | \
    tr -d '\n' | wc -m; done
5
7
```

Working with `wc` to get each line's count can be tricky. You have to call it for each string from column 3 individually which makes it a bit tricky to do what you want. You have to look through each row of your CSV, extract column 3 and then present it to `wc` to get the character count.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` and `awk`

```
sed 's/.*,.*,\(.*\),.*/\1/g' file | awk -v FS="" '{print NF;}'
```

Example:

```
$ (echo abd,123,egypt,78; echo cde,456,england,45;) | sed 's/.*,.*,\(.*\),.*/\1/g' | awk -v FS="" '{print NF;}'
5
7
```

Two awk's

```
awk -F, '{print $3}' file | awk -v FS="" '{print NF;}'
```

Example:

```
$ (echo abd,123,egypt,78; echo cde,456,england,45;) | awk -F, '{print $3}'| awk -v FS="" '{print NF;}'
5
7
```